# Url Rewrite - Add Query String Too 999

Tags: .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^tags tags.php [L,NC]

    </IfModule>
```

i want to add new page .but  write page not found. why? please help me.

RewriteRule ^tags tags.php [L,NC] // i want this www.example.com/tags open tags.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your htaccess rules like this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^tags/?$ tags.php [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


    </IfModule>
```

The problem is that, your rule

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Rewrites any request (not a true file/dir) to index.php. since /tags is not  an existent file on your directory, so a request for http://example.com/tags was being rewritten to /index.php and the last rule(s) never executed.